# PDO timing in CANopen

Tags: can-bus, canopen

According to CANopen, it does this to synchronize the two structures. One is to synchronize the overall NMT process, and the other is to determine when to send the PDO.

How can the processing time of PDOs be determined so that the synchronous window time can be set?

Comment: What you are asking for is "how to write a requirements specification when designing a bus implementation". You write down the requirements then implement them. The implementation of the nodes has to fall in line or they are not suitable. However the accuracy of CANopen timing is probably not better than millisecond accuracy. I don't remember exactly which time units you set up the various PDO features like event timer, inhibit timer etc.

Comment: @Lundin Right, I meant how much time it usually takes to run a PDO.

Comment: A CAN frame with 11 bit id usually has ~47 bits overhead, say 50 bits for a few bit stuffing bits here and there. Add the number of data bits to that. The time to send one bit is t=1/f where the frequency is your baudrate.